# ITextSharp - While Rendering HTML in a ColumnText, it's getting disappeared

Tags: html, itext

I am using the ITextSharp for creating a PDF document. As part of creating a document, I have to render a HTML block in a window of a particular page. I am using the below code to render the HTML. Surprisingly it is not rendering the HTML.
I have attached the HTML [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5k0tl_3rFgebkYzZUNUT2JFWlU)

```
public override Rectangle Draw(Rectangle curRectangle)
    {
        try
        {
            var column = new ColumnText(this.DocRenderer.PdfDocContentByte);
            string css = "p {font-family:HELVETICA; font-style:normal; color:black; font-size:10px}"
                + " li {font-family:HELVETICA; font-style:normal; color:black;font-size:10px}";
            foreach (var element in XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(FileContents of guide.html, css))
            {
                column.AddElement(element);
            }

            curRectangle = this.SimulateHeight(curRectangle, column);
            column.SetSimpleColumn(curRectangle);
            column.Go(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        return curRectangle;
    }

    private Rectangle SimulateHeight(Rectangle curRectangle,ColumnText column)
    {

        float top = 15;
        column.SetSimpleColumn(curRectangle.Left, curRectangle.Bottom, curRectangle.Right, top);
        int status = column.Go(true);
        top = column.YLine-1;
        return new Rectangle(curRectangle.Left, curRectangle.Bottom, curRectangle.Right, top);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it only is simulating, your line

```
int status = column.Go(true);
```

swallows all composite content added to `column` if all that content fits into the rectangle. (This allows to easily simulate drawing yet more composite content to the same `ColumnText`.)

Thus, if the `status` value is `ColumnText.NO_MORE_TEXT`, you'll have to add it again, e.g. like this:

```
private iTextSharp.text.Rectangle SimulateHeight(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle curRectangle, ColumnText column)
{
    var compositeContent = new List<IElement>(column.CompositeElements);
    float top = 15;
    column.SetSimpleColumn(curRectangle.Left, curRectangle.Bottom, curRectangle.Right, top);
    int status = column.Go(true);
    if (ColumnText.NO_MORE_TEXT == status)
    {
        foreach (var element in compositeContent)
        {
            column.AddElement(element);
        }
    }
    top = column.YLine - 1;
    return new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curRectangle.Left, curRectangle.Bottom, curRectangle.Right, top);
}
```

---

Actually even for other `status` values that list may be *partially* emptied of the top level elements that did fit. In your case, though, there is but one top level element, the `div`, so if that does not fit completely, it remains.

---

As an aside, you use a `top` value located near to the actual bottom of the page, so it actually is the bottom y coordinate. Such a naming is quite misleading.